# Cannot assign value of type 'Class<T>' to type 'protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?'

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm hoping someone has run into this before.  I'm trying to assign this class to be the delegate for the UIImagePickerController and I'm getting this error:

"PictureViewController.swift:40:32: Cannot assign value of type 'PictureViewController' to type 'protocol?'"

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import MVCarouselCollectionView
import Eureka
import RealmSwift

public class PictureViewController<T: Equatable>: FormViewController, TypedRowControllerType,
            MVCarouselCollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    public var row: RowOf<T>!
    public var completionCallback : ((UIViewController) -> ())?
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "loadImageButtonTapped:"), animated: true)

        imagePicker.delegate = self  <<<==== THIS GIVES ERROR MESSAGE
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Actually I figured it out.  I just had to also declare that this class implements the UINavigationControllerDelegate and all works now.